# How can i rotate a Label or Button in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I used QtDesigner to create a Gui.
Now i want to rotate a button (m1 in my code) or label.
i have read something about QTransform, but it didn't work,
can anybody help me?

code:
https://www.ppaste.org/zzwNqb7hI
or
https://www.ppaste.org/4oTcTykBt

Comment: Please avoid using external sites for your code, and include it in the question; also, always provide code as [minimal, reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then, what have you tried with QTransform that "didn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

To rotate Label You can use code as below:

```
        angle = 90  # What angle would you like to rotate
        self.pixmap = QPixmap("img\\label.png") # image for your label
        pixmap_rotated = self.pixmap.transformed(QTransform().rotate(angle),QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        self.imageLabel.setPixmap(pixmap_rotated) # set rotated pixmap into your QLabel
```

As you didn't provide any reproducible code, it's just an example of how you could use QTransform to rotate QLabel.